# What is the difference between F[A] and A?

Tags: scala, haskell, types

For languages like Scala and Haskell, you can construct types using type constructors. What is the right vocabulary for differentiating between all of these parts?

`A` is a type. `F[A]` is also a type. Is there language that exists to differentiate the two?

What is `A`?

What is `F[A]`?

What is `F`?

Comment: AFAIK there's no obvious standard distinguishing term for `F[A]` because it's not a particularly useful distinction. `A` and `F[A]` are types, `F` is a type constructor.

Comment: I would borrow the terminology from functions.  In `F[A]`, `A` is the argument, `F[A]` is perhaps the result, `F` is the type constructor.  Sometimes it's contextual though, if you give an example sentence or two I might be more helpful.

Comment: No specific context, really. To me, there seems to be something lacking that `A` and `F[A]` are reduced to the word `type`. There's something more complex about `F[A]` that I feel isn't being articulated. If I had to venture a guess I would go with "constructed type or compound type vs primitive type or base type" but I wanted to check if this was already solved for in the wild.

Comment: `F` is often called a `Functor`. In haskell, the class type `Functor` is used to categorize such types.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Not all type constructors are functors.

Comment: @MarkCanlas We don’t normally call tuples and lists “compound values” to contrast them with “atomic values” like numbers or booleans. Why do you feel such nomenclature must exist for types? Indeed, I think the fact that such terminology doesn’t exist hints at a broader point, which is that a type is a type, and rarely is it meaningful to distinguish types built out of other types from “atomic” types.

Comment: Consider two type constructors `newtype F f = F (f (F f))` and `data NF a  = Z | S a`. Which would you consider more complex: the type `F NF` or the type `Integer`? (The two types, of course, aren't equivalent, but it goes to show that the complexity you are talking about is more related to implementation than any fundamental property of the resulting types.)

Comment: @MarkCanlas `5` is an expression with a value, and `5 + 2` is also an expression with a value; likewise `f(x)`, for some appropriate function `f`. They don't need special names to indicate that one is the result of a function call and one is a literal; they are just values. Likewise at the type level, a standalone type and a type produced by applying a type constructor to some type parameters are the same thing, regardless of how you produced them.

Answer (score 4):

Dunno about in Scala, but in Haskell, the Report does distinguish between two syntactic categories: "types" and "constructors". Constructors are just those types which are single atoms, beginning with an upper case letter, and created by `data` and `newtype` declarations. e.g.

```
data Foo a = Bar
```

creates a new type constructor `Foo` (and a new data constructor `Bar`), and types can be formed by applying `Foo` to another type. Of course, constructors need not be of higher kind; `data Baz = Quux` also declares a type constructor named `Baz` which is not permitted to be applied to any other types.

(But beware: it is common to use "type constructor" to mean "any type-level expression with an arrow kind", so if you are doing some technical writing, you should include some text in your introduction clarifying which of these two meanings you intend to use in the rest of the document.)

So, in your example, we could say `Map` is a constructor, `Char` is a constructor, `Int` is a constructor, `Map Char` is a type, and `Map Char Int` is a type.

As far as I know, there is no common shorthand term for any of these categories: "a type which is definitely not a constructor", "a type of kind `*`", "a type which is definitely not of kind `*`". For types which are allowed to be applied to another type, there is the term "higher-kinded type" -- e.g. `Map` and `Map Char` are both higher-kinded types.

Comment: What is "the Report"?

Comment: @MarkCanlas The Haskell Language Report, very easily googled: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean when you say `Char` is a constructor and `Int` is a constructor? That sounds counter-intuitive.

Comment: @MarkCanlas `Char` and `Int` are [*nullary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity#Nullary) type constructors? Once you have the whole machinery, there is just no good reason to treat parameterless types any different from all the other type constructors, I guess...

Comment: @MarkCanlas I'm not sure what more I can say about that than what I put in my answer. They tick all the boxes: `Char` is a single lexical atom, starts with an upper case letter, and was notionally created by a `data` declaration. (Okay, so it is actually built into the compiler and not created by a `data` declaration. But in principle it's just a big enumeration, something you could make yourself if you had the patience to type out 1114111 unique data constructor names.) You are probably falling into the trap I mentioned in paragraph two. "Constructor" doesn't necessarily mean "parameterized".

Answer (score 4):

The technical terms, as mentioned in the comments, are 'type', 'some other type', and a 'type constructor'.

Consider:

```
 data A = A
  --  ^   ^--- The Data Constructor
  --  -- The type

data F   x = SomeDataConstructorForF x
 --  ^   ^     ^-- Data Constr       ^-- Field
 --  |   --- Type Variable
 --  - Type Constructor

val :: A
val = A
-- A value of type 'A'

val2 :: F [A]
val2 = SomeDataConstructorForF []
-- A value of some other type, F [A].
-- No special term exists for types built through application
-- of one or more type constructor afaik
```

Answer (score 4):

I would propose to just call `F[A]` **application** of a **type constructor** `F` of kind `* -> *` to the argument `A` of kind `*`. ["Type constructor"](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#type-constructors) comes from the specification, whereas "application" comes from the basic lambda calculus, as explained below.

Recall that the formalism of [higher-kinded types with all the type constructors is essentially just an extension of a simply typed lambda calculus over a single type `*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)).

That means that you have the following rules for forming kinds:

1. `*` is a kind
2. if `a`, `b` are kinds, then `a -> b` is a kind

You can form terms as follows:

1. Predefined constants with fixed kind are terms
2. Variables are terms
3. If `f` and `a` are terms, then the **application** `f a` is a term
4. If `x` is a variable name, and `y` is a term, then the *abstraction* `\x.y` is a term

You can check whether a (type-valued) term is well-kinded with rules that look somewhat like this:

1. Predefined constant `c` of kind `k` (vacuously) has kind `k`, regardless of context
2. If context `Gamma` contains mapping of a variable `v` to kind `k`, then in `Gamma` we can infer that `v` is a well-kinded expression of kind `k`.
3. If in context `Gamma` we can infer that `f` has kind `a -> b` and `x` has kind `a`, then the **application** `f x` has kind `b`.
4. If in context `Gamma, x: a` we can infer that `y` has kind `b`, then in `Gamma` we can infer that `\x.y` has kind `a -> b`.

I don't see any reason to invent any new vocabulary, so I would just use "application".

---

An aside: you can actually write down the above basic kind-inference algorithm really quickly.

```
sealed trait Term
case class Apply(func: Term, arg: Term) extends Term
case class Lam(preferred: String, dom: Type, body: Term) extends Term

case class BoundVar(deBruijnIdx: Int) extends Term
case class FreeVar(name: String) extends Term

sealed trait Type
case object * extends Type
case class Func(dom: Type, cod: Type) extends Type {
  override def toString = s"($dom -> $cod)"
}

import util.{Either, Left, Right}

case class Ctx(globalConstants: Map[String, Type], stack: List[Type]) {
  def push(tp: Type): Ctx = Ctx(globalConstants, tp :: stack)
  def pop: Ctx = Ctx(globalConstants, stack.tail)
}

object Ctx {
  def empty = Ctx(Map.empty, List.empty)
  def emptyWithGlobals(keys: (String, Type)*) = Ctx(keys.toMap, Nil)
}

def tinf(t: Term, ctx: Ctx = Ctx.empty): Either[String, Type] = t match {
  case FreeVar(v) => 
    ctx.globalConstants.get(v).map(Right(_)).getOrElse(Left("Undefined: " + v))
  case BoundVar(d) => Right(ctx.stack(d))
  case Apply(f, x) => 
    for {
      tf <- tinf(f, ctx)
      tx <- tinf(x, ctx)
      res <- tf match {
        case Func(a, b) =>
          if (tx == a) Right(b)
          else Left(s"Type mismatch: cannot apply `$a` to `$b`")
        case sthElse => Left(s"Not applicable: $sthElse")
      }
    } yield res
  case Lam(_, tp, b) => 
    for {
      tb <- tinf(b, ctx.push(tp))
    } yield Func(tp, tb)
}

for {
  example <- List(
    Lam("x", *, BoundVar(0)),
    Lam("x", *, Lam("y", Func(*, *), Apply(BoundVar(0), BoundVar(1))))
  )
} println(example + " : " + tinf(example))
```

and it will happily infer that type-lambdas

```
\(x:*).x
\(x:*).\y(* -> *). y x
```

have the kinds

```
(* -> *)
(* -> ((* -> *) -> *))
```

respectively.

Comment: The Scala spec uses both "Parameterized Types" (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#parameterized-types) and "application".